# .htaccess call PHP file with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry if the title of the question is not clear, please read below for details;

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/home/.*$ index.php [QSA]
```

One of its functions is to redirect the url from this example:

```
www.example.com/user.php?user=david
```

to be:

```
www.example.com/david
```

Now, I have a file `friends.php` which function is to show friends of a particular user.
So the link that I wanted is like this:

```
www.example.com/david/friends
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What should `www.example.com/david/friends` be rewritten to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to basically do the same as you did for user. In fact, the rule does not even conflict, because the user rule cannot contain a `/` character.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/friends$ friends.php?user=$1 [L]
```